# Concatenating pathname with a virtual URL for Tracking PageView

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm using the Contact Form 7 plugin for Wordpress.
It allows you to put in a single line of javascript in the additional settings to trigger some javascript code when the send button is pressed.

My original code looked like this, which works fine:

```
on_sent_ok: "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/CallbackFormFilled']);"
```

The "On_sent_ok:" is a specific parameter for the contact form.
I have a requirement where i need to concatenate the pathname of the URL together with the virtual URL i have created in the code above.

I tested concatenation of strings using 'Alert' to make sure i was doing it correctly, but when using the following code my pageview tracking fails

What is the correct syntax for concatenating the strings correctly here?

```
on_sent_ok: "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',window.location.pathname+'CallbackFormFilled']);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',"/"+window.location.pathname+'CallbackFormFilled']);"
```

Comment: I get "_gaq is undefined" as a javascript error in javascript console?

Comment: Last week i found one possible solution: I added the following code
    `on_sent_ok: " var x=window.location.pathname+'CallbackFormFilled';var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', x]);"`


This gave me no javascript errors, the contact form processed correctly also. However, my Google analytics shows no goal conversions. Its possible thats just a coincidence but im wondering if there is more to it?